# Iterating over ListView data

Tags: c#, listview, datatable, datarow

I have a ListView which is bound to a DataTable. I would like to iterate over the DataTable's rows and access their data. I figured, to do this, I would simply iterate over the ListViewDataItems in the ListView. To test that I am properly accessing the data, I tried the following code, which should simply print the string at column 0 for each row.

```
for (int i = 0; i < MyListView.Items.Count; i++)
{
    ListViewDataItem item = MyListView.Items[i];
    DataRow row = (DataRow) item.DataItem;
    Response.Write(row[0]);
}
```

However, nothing is printed. To verify that the ListView is not empty (which it shouldn't be as the data is properly rendered on my aspx page), I tried this:

```
Response.Write(MyListView.Items.Count);
```

This prints the number 16, which is correct as there are 16 rows in my ListView. I'm guessing I'm just not accessing the data correctly. I'd appreciate some insight on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided the best solution was to just iterate over the data directly in the `DataTable` rather than the ListViewDataItems.

```
for (int i = 0; i < myTable.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < myTable.Columns.Count; j++)
    {
        object data = data.Rows[i][j];
        // do stuff with data
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to stop on breakpoint (at line  DataRow row = (DataRow) item.DataItem;) and simply to check what you have .

for example like here :http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173083(v=VS.90).aspx

Comment: It appears that ListViewDataItem item is being set to null.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still seeking the correct answer to this question, the following code will work (VB.NET):

```
Dim di as ListViewDataItem

For Each di in MyListView.Items
    Response.Write(CType(di.FindControl("ExampleLabel"), Label).Text)
Next
```

Just substitute the `Response.Write` line with whatever you wanted to do to each list item. The example line is looking for a control called 'ExampleLabel', casts it back to a label then writes the text value onto the page.

Easily adapted to C# for anyone proficient (not I alas).